# How to Seal Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, template, ovirt

I'm trying to prepare Windows 7 Template, i have used Sysprep.exe with the following options:

1. Under System Cleanup Action, select Enter System Out-of-Box-Experience (OOBE).
2. Tick the Generalize check box.
3. Under Shutdown Options, select Shutdown.

When booting the image on new machine:
The the machine still has the same user profile.

Is there a way to set this? and to delete the current user ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, sysprep is used to prepare an image to be used as a deployment image.

Secondly, if you are in audit mode, you add your programs, drivers, etc., and you then should finalise with the Out-of-Box-Experience option which will clear the SIDs but maintain the changes you made in Audit Mode. (Just make sure that you have Audit mode on prior to selecting OOBE)

Lastly, make sure you do your sysprep -> check OOBE, if it fails (which it has in this case), add this to your oobeSystem configuration file:

```
Microsoft-Windows-Deployment | Reseal |Mode= oobe
```

Alternatively, read through the TechNet document here:

```
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh824920.aspx
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! seems i'm missed the audit mode, now i configured it from admin account and then once installing on new machine the admin account is disable automatically.